# Tensorflow TypeError: Can not convert a NoneType into a Tensor or Operation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am learning TensorFlow and was going through [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/use-word-embedding-layers-deep-learning-keras/) step-by-step guide. The below code is the exact same as on the website. However, when running it, I get an error when trying to fit the model. The full traceback I get is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\users\name\desktop\python ml tutorial\embedding.py", line 49, in <module>
    model.fit(x=padded_docs, y=labels, epochs=50, verbose=0)
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1213, in fit
    self._make_train_function()
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 316, in _make_train_function
    loss=self.total_loss)
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\optimizer_v2\optimizer_v2.py", line 506, in get_updates
    return [self.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars)]
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\optimizer_v2\optimizer_v2.py", line 441, in apply_gradients
    kwargs={"name": name})
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py", line 1917, in merge_call
    return self._merge_call(merge_fn, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py", line 1924, in _merge_call
    return merge_fn(self._strategy, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\optimizer_v2\optimizer_v2.py", line 494, in _distributed_apply
    with ops.control_dependencies(update_ops):
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py", line 5257, in control_dependencies
    return get_default_graph().control_dependencies(control_inputs)
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\func_graph.py", line 356, in control_dependencies
    return super(FuncGraph, self).control_dependencies(filtered_control_inputs)
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py", line 4691, in control_dependencies
    c = self.as_graph_element(c)
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py", line 3610, in as_graph_element
    return self._as_graph_element_locked(obj, allow_tensor, allow_operation)
  File "C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py", line 3699, in _as_graph_element_locked
    (type(obj).__name__, types_str))
TypeError: Can not convert a NoneType into a Tensor or Operation.
```

And the full code is below:

```
from numpy import array
from keras.preprocessing.text import one_hot
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers.embeddings import Embedding

# define document
docs = ['Well done!',
        'Good work',
        'Great effort',
        'nice work',
        'Excellent!',
        'Weak',
        'Poor effort!',
        'not good',
        'poor work',
        'Could have done better.']

# define class labels
labels = array([1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0])

# integer-encode the documents
vocab_size = 50
encoded_docs = [one_hot(d, vocab_size) for d in docs]
print(encoded_docs)

# padding
max_length = 4
padded_docs = pad_sequences(encoded_docs, maxlen = max_length, padding = 'post')
print(padded_docs)

# define model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(vocab_size, 8, input_length=max_length))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

# compile the model
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# summarize
print(model.summary())

# fit the model
model.fit(x=padded_docs, y=labels, epochs=50, verbose=0)

# evaluate the model
loss, accuracy = model.evaluate(x=padded_docs, y=labels, verbose=0)
print("Accuracy: {}".format(accuracy))
```

What's going on here? The article was originally written back in 2017 but its last revision and update was just a week ago. I imagine they are constantly tweaking TensorFlow since it is still state-of-the-art and needs a lot of improvement.

Any ideas on how to circumvent this?

**Edit:**
I began trying to figure out where the script could have gone wrong. I will be listing what I found here, hopefully it will help us spot something:

- I found that in `ops.py`'s `control_dependencies()` function, `control_inputs` parameter has the following values: `Tensor("Adam/gradients/gradients/loss/dense_1_loss/binary_crossentropy/logistic_loss_grad/Reshape_1:0", shape=(None, 1), dtype=float32)`, `Tensor("Adam/gradients/gradients/loss/dense_1_loss/binary_crossentropy/logistic_loss/Log1p_grad/mul:0", shape=(None, 1), dtype=float32)`, and `None`. When it becomes `None`, the program crashes.

Comment: Can you verify the keras version you are using? I just ran the code you provided in colab and it ran perfectly fine.

Comment: I have keras 2.3.0. I have just seen the newest version is 2.4.3 currently. So dumb of me. What is your version?

Comment: Its running on 2.4.3

Comment: Alright, I updated it and it works now! Thanks a ton, I should have checked my versions before!